# check if any window is open in a Qt application

Tags: qt

I have an application in Qt and it has a tray icon. I dont want to open the tray icon menu if any of the window is open in the application. In effect i want to prevent the user from opening multiple windows simultaneously. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if any of your windows are opened with isHidden() method. If you don't have list of your windows you may go with QApplication::topLevelWidgets(), but it's not the best idea.